# HTTPS And Node.Js Just Won't work

Tags: node.js, https

I'm building a JSON service using Node.Js and Journey. Everything was working great over HTTP but I needed to make it work over HTTPS. I believe I've implemented HTTPS correctly but not matter what I do the HTTPS connection is killed during the handshake.

```
var http = require('https');
//CODE
var httpsServer = http.createServer({ pfx: fs.readFileSync('SSLCertificate_Wildcard.pfx') }, function (request, response) {
    console.log('Incoming Request', { url: request.url });
    request.on('end', function () {
        router.handle(request, body, function (route) {
             //CODE
        });     
    });  
});
httpsServer.listen(11555);
```

I've attached event handlers for "checkContinue", "connection", "connect", "upgrade", "clientError", and "error" and only "connection" is ever raised.

Comment: I'm assuming you did `var http = require('https');`, but that makes things look confusing in your code.

Comment: yes. I did that because I was I admit lazy and didn't feel like switching every reference of `http` to `https`. I'll edit the question to mention that though.

Comment: Do you see your `Incoming Request` logged to the console? If you don't see any errors, how/when do you know the connection is killed during the handshake?

Comment: I know it's killed during the handshake because that's what fiddler tells me

Answer (score 0):

do you even see a request going out from chrome via chrome developer tools network tab?
https works great from experience so my guess is that its either not going out or its going out as http by mistake.
also i hope you are not running from http website, a https json call since thats a security issue and would be blocked by chrome. you must run https website to enable https calls from client.

Comment: The request goes out since
1) I see it sent in the dev tools
2) I've sent it using fiddler with same result

Comment: if it fails due to handshake thats a security issue. is your website running in https as well? do you use same certificate in your website and that server that exposes the json?

Comment: Just hitting the url, no AJAX yet, just typing the json call url directly into the address bar

Comment: so its possible the browser didn't find an encryption algo suited with the server. look at https://github.com/andris9/pem to generate a development pem files for the https server and test with it. i know i'm using it and it works great. var https = require('https'),
    pem = require('pem');

pem.createCertificate({days:1, selfSigned:true}, function(err, keys){
    https.createServer({key: keys.serviceKey, cert: keys.certificate}, function(req, res){
        res.end("o hai!")
    }).listen(443);
});

Comment: I tried that but now node exits without ever calling the callback to createCertificate

Comment: without an error? unlikely. check that link for docs how to set it up. they got several examples. they are working good for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65230/discussion-between-shmuelie-and-sagie-gur-ari).